# JQuery Validation - positioning a particular error message within the list

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have removed a lot of the code to make it easier for you to see, but in essence I have something like the following

```
$("#my-form").validate({
    focusInvalid: false,
    errorContainer: "#validation",
    errorLabelContainer: "#validation",
    errorElement: "li",
    onfocusout: false,
    onkeyup: false,
    groups: {
        fileGroup: "fileOne fileTwo"
    },
    rules: {
        fullName: {
            required: true,
            maxlength: 50
        },
        emailAdd: {
            emailRule: true,
            maxlength: 80,
            required: true
        },
        fileOne: {
            accept: "image/bmp, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg, image/png, image/tiff, application/pdf",
            filesize: 2097152,
            require_from_group: [1, '.fileGroup']
        }
    },
    ...
```

At the moment, my errors are displayed in my container as list items, as I want them to be. However, the fileOne message always seems to be displayed at the top of the list, when I need it displayed at the bottom.

I have tried adding errorPlacement, but this does not seem to work alongside the error commands I currently have. Is there any other way to make sure that the file message is displayed last in the list, and not first?

Thanks

Comment: Just as a quick suggestion, perhaps the order of declaration will effect that? Can you try: `fileGroup: "fileTwo fileOne"` ?

Comment: That does not change anything.  I need fileOne and fileTwo messages displayed after all of my other elements

Comment: After your other rules? Hm. I think you may need to use some sort of onvalidated callback and manually sort that list. I do not think there is an automated hook for the ordering.

Comment: The `errorPlacement` option has absolutely nothing to do with the ordering of messages within your list container.  It's only used for individual message placement near each input element.  You'll need to show your relevant HTML markup so a demo can be constructed.

Comment: I am struggling with this too. All errors should be displayed in the order that the fields are displayed, no matter when they were validated. Any solution available yet?